# Python requests not pulling correct date range of data

Tags: python, python-requests, sdk, noaa

I've been using requests to get station data for a few years now. I'm using the following code:

```
url = 'https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/data?datasetid=GHCND&datatypeid=TMAX&limit=1000&stationid=GHCND:{StationID}&startdate={'2020-01-01'}&enddate={'2020-12-31'}
        dates_temp, temps = [], []
        r = requests.get(url, headers={'token': 'My_token'})
        d = json.loads(r.text)
        try:
            data_temps = [item for item in d['results'] if item['datatype'] == 'TMAX']
            dates_temp += [item['date'] for item in data_temps]
            temps += [item['value'] for item in data_temps]
```

It is still **mostly** working. However, no matter what station I try or what year, it will not pull January/February. The first row of data coming back is always either 2/28 or 3/1. This was not the case a few years ago. I checked the NOAA interface (downloading a report directly) and the data is there. I'm also testing it with stations which I've used before and which I know **should** have data.

What's the deal? Was there an update to the NOAA feed through requests? Is there a v3 of the API link? I'm reluctant to entirely rewrite all my code to go the SDK library route - partly because I already have this code that's been pretty stable (and I'm hoping I just need to fix something small), but also partly because I used to use the RNOAA library with R and there was significantly less data that would come through the API than I could get with requests.

Comment: the api is still on v2

Comment: can i get a station id

Comment: there is a bug in the api, you need to open a ticker on their website or email them. i took of the station id and got the same results starting at 2/28 for all stations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem a few days ago and I reported the failure to NOAA's help email.
They have answered that V2 API is deprecated and the documentation for the new one is located in the "Tools for Developers" section of this web: https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/access

They have also let me know this:

"In the new API, you must download data by reporting station (no spatial queries are permitted for data access, only for metadata discovery)."

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much! I thought perhaps this was the case, but I was looking for v3 code, not v1, which I suspect is why I didn't find it. I implemented this and it took me less than an hour to fix everything, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is sadly to store data retrieved from a third party API in your database. Other people's APIs are very unreliable and they are slow to fix them. Government APIs are the worst because the project probably has little to no funding